# Journey from arecord to mcasp codecs

Tags: davinci

Can anyone help me understand how the flow happens from alsa utility arecord to mcasp codecs (davinvi-mcasp.c) startup functions?

As we can specify the sound card and the device (arecord -Dhw:1,0), I assume asla already has been instructed which kernel module (which is pcm5102a in my case) it should use.

But what happens here, how does the flow reach from pcm5102a to other mcasp modules like davinci-mcasp.c, etc?